# Removing null values from bag after group?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following:

(id: int, names: chararray)

And I group by id, creating a bag of names. I see that in the bag of names, there may be a null value. How do I remove null values from the bag?

Comment: don't put it in, in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FILTER nested in FOREACH to remove tuples from the bag created by GROUP BY.

```
inpt = LOAD '...' as (id: int, names: chararray);
grp = GROUP inpt BY id;
result = FOREACH grp {
   no_nulls = FILTER inpt BY names is not null;
  GENERATE group, no_nulls;
};
```

Or just filter null names before grouping:

```
inpt = LOAD '...' as (id: int, names: chararray);
no_nulls = FILTER input BY names is not null;
grp = GROUP no_nulls BY id;
```